# Singular covariance matrix in GMM?

Tags: covariance-matrix, generalized-moments

I understand that typically the covariance matrix should not be singular (see e.g. this discussion here: [Could the covariance matrix of the moment conditions in GMM be ill-conditioned?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215604/could-the-covariance-matrix-of-the-moment-conditions-in-gmm-be-ill-conditioned))

But in the documentation of Mike Cliff's GMM package for Matlab (https://sites.google.com/site/mcliffweb/programs; https://sites.google.com/site/mcliffweb/filebox/gmmdoc.pdf?attredirects=0) there is the following paragraph (page 8):

[image]

This is quite confusing to me. No qualification w.r.t.weighting matrix optimality is in aforementioned question on Stackoverflow. So which of these two statements is correct, or what am I missing here?